# An elaboration of a solution.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, summation

The question and its solution are given below:

[image]

[image]

I am doubting if the solution is correct or no, for my opinion I see that most of it is correct .....  but I do not understand the last part, that is   how $$(a) \sum_{d|{p^k}} \sigma(d) = \sum_{i = 0}^k (k +1 - i)p^i$$, also I do not understand how last equality in the other sum is calculated, could anyone explain this for me please?

Comment: The explanation is in the second displayed formula in part (a). The divisors of $p^k$ are $1,p,p^2,...,p^k$, for each of them you compute $\sigma$, which is the sum of their divisors. $\sigma(1)=1$, $\sigma(p)=1+p$, ..., $\sigma(p^k)=1+p+...+p^k$. The next step if adding copies of the same number. All the $1$'s are added together, all the $p$'s, all the $p^2$'s, etc.

Comment: I mean how is this last compact form calculated, I can not see it @logarithm

Comment: There is one $1$ in each parethesis. There are $k+1$ parenthesis. So, $(k+1-0)\cdot 1$. There is one $p$ in each parenthesis except the first one. So, $k+1-1$ copies of $p$. That is the $(k+1-1)\cdot p$. ... The is only one $p^k$, which appears in the last parenthesis. That is $1=(k+1-k)$. That is the $(k+1-k)\cdot p$.

Comment: what about the $i's$? @logarithm

Comment: $i=0,1,2,3,...k$; is the summation dummy variable.

Comment: what about the last equality in the other sum of the OP question .... how it is calculated? @logarithm